# Using Task.Run vs BackgroundService in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this simple minimal API:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// my long running process <----
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();    

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.Run();
```

And here is `MyBackgroundService`:

```cs
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while(stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);             // wait 1 second
            Console.WriteLine("doing work..."); // do work
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the same program written using a `Task` instead of using a background service:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// my long running process in a task instead of a background service
_ = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true) {
        await Task.Delay(1000);             // wait 1 second
        Console.WriteLine("doing work..."); // do work
    }
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.Run();
```

Why do tutorials and places on the internet encourage you to use `BackgroundService`? Will it be wrong practice if I use the second approach where I use Task.Run? What will be the difference of using the first approach vs using the second approach?

Comment: Because it’s the correct way to do long running tasks. There’s a limited amount of tasks run at once, for one. Also you don’t have any way to stop it

Comment: I know it is the correct way. I just want to know why. I have a way of stopping it by adding a cancelation token.

Comment: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html), by Stephen Cleary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you.

Basically, it's a question of whether to use the existing framework or do it your own way.

If it's a mini project for up to 3 people and you're not planning to deploy to Azure, I wouldn't be afraid to use a your own solution - `Task`.
Otherwise, I would reach for `BackgroundService`.

Nicely described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

- `BackgroundService` allows integration into a larger ecosystem with rich monitoring capabilities
- `Task` is always available, straightforward and simple - but you solve everything yourself

Tip: look for your piece of code

```cs
_ = Task.Run(async () => ...
```

are you sure that that discard `_` is ok?

Comment: I was just curious to see if there was a performance impact on using `Task.Run` implementations. I guess not based on `Basically, it's a question of whether to use the existing framework or do it your own way.` And it makes sense to use the existing framework instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "are you sure that that discard _ is ok?" That probably to prevent some warning by ReSharper or so. I see that a lot

Comment: My tip was directed to an idea: by discarding the Task instance, I lose control over the running task instance - I can't execute Task.Wait, for example. So I understand the information about resharper, but it's not what I was pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

After review the source code of [the `Host` class](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/Internal/Host.cs,56), I am pretty sure that a `BackgroundService` is a normal task except for the following features:

1. It gets notified when the application starts or stops.
2. It handles exceptions like `OperationCanceledException`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question about software architecture (even if you don't realize it).

Sure you can put everything in one big file, heck you don't even need those things called "subroutines". I mean in the 60s they could work perfectly fine without them.... but of course programs were quite small back then.

To keep software maintainable, testable, reliable, etc many software development techniques have combined into certain "architectures", "principles", "guidelines", etc. i.e. the way programs are build.

Let's start with "subroutines". Those weren't always there. At one moment somebody discovered that repeating code could be put in a separate place and called over and over. And it tuned out that separating code out made it better readible, maintainable, testable etc.

Another one of these is inversion of control, say dependency injection. This one is used for the background service, where you can resolve and inject other services during the construction of the bg service object.

Another one is the singleton, i.e. there being one and only one instance of the worker. Of course you could make that yourself, but the framework offers you a standardized way to build such a singleton background worker. So it's a kind of a "builder" which is also a design pattern. Which helps you with another principle: don't repeat yourself. Don't repeat yourself.

Are you slowly starting to see the big picture?

Comment: I was just curious to see why people recommended using background service. And the reason is because of architecture as you described it. It makes a lot of sense. I just was curious if that was the only reason.